# Find the area under the curve with a sketch

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the value but do not know how because I am not given an intial value.. Any help?
[image: homework]

Comment: The question is asking for the value of $x$ so that the area between the x-axis and the curve from 0 to $x$ is around -0.5. For instance, $x = 0.5$ wouldn't be the right answer because the net area between 0 and 0.5 looks like -4.5, not -0.5.

Comment: okay, that makes sense. I just have no idea what the value is..

Comment: You're supposed to just estimate. For instance the answer is definitely not 1, or 1.5, or 2... Just keep going until you get something so that the net area is around -0.5

Comment: I tried that, and wasted all but 1 try. I have no idea what to do..

Comment: Hmm... The area from 0 to 1.5 looks around -0.75. When x is 2 the area above is around 1/2(0.5)(0.2) = 0.05 so the total area is around -0.7 so that still won't work. But when x is 2.5 the area above looks like a triangle with base 1 and height 0.5, so the area is around 0.25 So when you take the integral from 0 to 2.5, the area should be around -0.75 + 0.25 = -0.5. So I think the answer should be 2.5.

Comment: well, it was 2.5, but it also wanted the answer of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use Lagrange Interpolation to find a good approximation for that thing and then integrate. This will give a good approximation of the area under the curve depending on how many points you use.